# Testing Firebase without an Android application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm learning to use Firebase for Push notification.
I need to test whether my web application receives notification through Firebase. But I need to do this without an android application.

Any suggestions or is this impossible. Appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client

Comment: Thanks, will check this. Basically Im trying to get a notification from GCM to my web application. I'm unable to find a way to do that. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Firebase is not limited to android. BNKs link will help you